# Wordpress redirect users to log in only in specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress, I want to redirect users to log in if they enter specific locations in my webiste that start with a certain url.

e.g. force login if they enter any page that starts with `https://mysite/people`

so force login for 
`https://mysite/people/`

`https://mysite/people/home`

`https://mysite/people/about`

`https://mysite/people/*` <-anything that begins with that

I'm not sure how to do this in WP.

I've tried the plug in `wp-force-login` but it's applied to the entire site. And the example I see on the wiki

```
/**
 * Filter Force Login to allow exceptions for specific URLs.
 *
 * @return array An array of URLs. Must be absolute.
 */
function my_forcelogin_whitelist( $whitelist ) {
  // Get visited URL without query string
  $url_path = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

  // Whitelist URLs
  if ( '/page-name/' === $url_path ) {
    $whitelist[] = site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  }
  if ( '/page-name.php' === $url_path ) {
    $whitelist[] = site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  }
  return $whitelist;
}
add_filter('v_forcelogin_whitelist', 'my_forcelogin_whitelist', 10, 1);
```

How can I re-write this code to force login if they enter any page that only starts with `https://mysite/people`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `template_redirect` filter.  If a user not logged in visits this page they will be redirected to the WordPress login page.

```
function my_page_template_redirect() {
    $url_path = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    if( strpos($url_path, '/people/') !== 0 && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() );
        die;
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Is it safe to put this in Theme Functions (functions.php) file? This works great btw.

Comment: Yes mate stick in in there I should have mentioned that :)  If you're happy then please accept my answer :)

Comment: Sorry Andrew, after testing it it doesn't work like I thought it would. If I navigate to a url like `https://mysite/people/tools` it doesn't redirect me to log in. It only redirects me if I visit the specific url `https://mysite/people/`

Comment: So just include your previous code to check for the URL.

Comment: I thought I was going nuts doing that. It turns out requests to admin-ajax.php requests are all timing out or failing. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your sample code:

```
/**
 * Filter Force Login to allow exceptions for specific URLs.
 *
 * @return array An array of URLs. Must be absolute.
 */
function my_forcelogin_whitelist( $whitelist ) {
  // Get visited URL without query string
  $url_path = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

  // Whitelist URLs
  if ( '/page-name/' === $url_path ) {
    $whitelist[] = site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  }
  if ( '/page-name.php' === $url_path ) {
    $whitelist[] = site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  }
  return $whitelist;
}
add_filter('v_forcelogin_whitelist', 'my_forcelogin_whitelist', 10, 1);
```

The first command will remove page query (eg: `?name=john`). So, if you access url like `https://mysite/people/<sub-page1>/<sub-page2>?foo=bar`, `$url_path` is `/people/<sub-page1>/<sub-page2>`.

If you want to set all `people`'s sub-pages (`https://mysite/people/*`) as blacklist, it means all `$url_path`s which do not contain `/people/` at the beginning will become `$white_list`.

You can check that by strpos.

Here is the completed code:

```
/**
 * Filter Force Login to allow exceptions for specific URLs.
 *
 * @return array An array of URLs. Must be absolute.
 */
function my_forcelogin_whitelist( $whitelist ) {
  // Get visited URL without query string
  $url_path = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

  // Whitelist URLs
  // check if url_path is not /people + /...
  // at to white list
  if (strpos($url_path, '/people/') !== 0) {
    $whitelist[] = site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  }
  return $whitelist;
}
add_filter('v_forcelogin_whitelist', 'my_forcelogin_whitelist', 10, 1);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank for this answer! Do you find this approach with the plug in better than the answer I accepted? If so, why is it a better approach?

Comment: If you can resolve your problem without using any plugin, it's much better. My answer is only in cased that you are using `wp-force-login`. So, in my opinion, if you only want to force user login within pages that are `people`'s sub-page, you should remove the plugin and do a small hook like the answer you accepted, otherwise, keep your plugin, then you can custom more rules for it.

Comment: There is no proof that can prove using plugin is better or worse than customizing code in `function.php`. It depends on developers problems/issues/features and how they are resolved. I do not like using plugin for simple features, it causes my page be complex and dependent. And actually, I don't need them in this case. :D

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question but now I would rather do it with out the plug in I don't need that much functionality.

Comment: @Andrew Schultz did the big process for you. You can modify his code to use without using any plugin in this case by applying condition: `if (strpos($url_path, '/people/') !== 0 && !is_user_logged_in())`. It checks if url path is /people/ + sth and there is no user is logged in. He modified this answer to make it's right.